# Giving read access to all tables for an user and giving write acess to all tables for another user in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

Just a question. I created a login through the wizard and then associated an user with the login for a database; however, I have several database, do I have to create an user for all of them manually?

I created db_reader and db_writer.

After creating all the users for each database, can I run these commands:

```
REVOKE ALL
ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public 
FROM PUBLIC;

GRANT SELECT
ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public 
TO 'db_reader';



REVOKE ALL
ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public 
FROM PUBLIC;

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public 
TO 'db_writer';
```

Is there a way to double check using SELECT what accesses they have?

Or are there other things I need to do to achieve what I want? I am using MSSQL.

```
SQL Server Management Studio                        15.0.18338.0
SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)                     16.100.41011.9
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                        15.0.19205.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     10.0.19041.1
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 6.0 
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                        10.0.19044
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions in SQL Server are implicitly denied until explicitly granted. For every database that you want your Login to have access to, you'll need to create the corresponding User in that database, otherwise they won't have any access (unless otherwise a server level role grants those permissions to the Login, such as the `SysAdmin` role.)

So as long as you use your custom roles appropriately, there's no need for your `REVOKE ALL` scripts.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks. I checked and there were some default access roles, so I just picked the appropriate access roles for each user.

Comment: But the SQL scripts they work only for the user inside of the db where we call them right? So we need to call them for each user on each database separately? I am asking, because when I assigned the access roles, the users had access to several database already.

Comment: @online When you grant a **User** database specific permissions, they only apply to that specific **User** of that specific database. If a User already had permissions, it's possible they were derived from an Active Directory Group that was already granted permissions in the database, of which that User belongs to. `Domain Users` is a common Active Directory Group that developers unknowingly grant permissions to, resulting in over-provisioning accidentally. The `Domain Users` Active Directory Group represents all Users of the domain. Perhaps you ran into a similar situation?